# Mandatory Native Language on Profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it would be useful if users were forced to select their primary language on their profiles.

I understand people like their privacy, but I don't think selecting your primary language would be such a breach on it, and it could be very useful.

Many times you see posts where is clear the OP is having issues to convey their ideas in English.

It would be great for me if you coul know what is their primary language, or what other languages they can speak, because if I happened to be able to speak the same languages I could possibly help them to convey their ideas better on a separate chat and help them fix their SO post.

I think something like this would open more posibilities to help others without a significant change, and taking the issue to a separate chat is optional anyway so it wouldn't really affect the normal flow of the Site.

Finally this could be mandatory from now on, so there wouldn't be issues with existing users profiles.

Comment: I think users have to learn English first, because then SO will be a translation bureau.

Comment: @Yurets There's an SE for that: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Yurets - I agree with you, but sometimes there are basic things that are not clear. There are a bunch of people that think are being super clear, when they are not, if you could talk to them in their language they really know, you could understand them better and improve the quality of the posts in the site. However I do agree I wouldn't want users to feel like they can expect translations here.

Comment: _I could possibly help them to convey their ideas better on a separate chat and help them fix their SO post_ - OK, but can't you offer that help now anyway?

Comment: @BSMP - Well according to Makoto's answer we can't. But beyond that, ir is not always easy to tell what language other person speaks. For example Portuguese and Spanish, even assuming the user uses his real name, there are similarities in the names and the languages that make it hard to know, you could possibly ask the OP, but that is more clutter added to the site. Plus considering how many of us use nicknames, it is likely that more times than not the other person wouldn't speak a language you can.

Comment: _you could possibly ask the OP, but that is more clutter added to the site_ - How were you going to get the OP into a chat room to help them with their question without asking them? Even if the language is added to the profile, you'd still have to leave a comment asking them to join a chat room.

Comment: @BSMP - Yes, but that could be done in English. If they can't understand that much English they won't understand the answers to their questions anyway.

Comment: Then why can't you leave a comment like, "I speak [X,Y,Z languages]. If any of those is your native language, I'd like to help you improve your question. Please join me in chat room [link to chat room'."? If you have to leave a comment asking them to join chat anyway, why not ask if you speak their native language in the same comment?

Comment: @BSMP - Well of course I could do that, although apparently we shouldn't. But the proposal was to expedite the process. And also it is easier to redirect people to their Native Language site if you actually know what it is. It is all in the sake of saving time and resources, that's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think it would be useful if users were forced to select their primary language on their profiles.

I disagree to *force* a user to select the language preference. I would recommend to use the *comments* section to help the poster. To bring him to a chat room, you would anyway have to comment. Thus, I don't see a need of a new feature, the comments would be helpful anyway.

Please read the [official policy towards non-English questions on Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/).

It says,

> It is not, nor has it ever been, our goal to be the one place in the
> world for all programming information in every possible human
> language.
>
> Thus:
>
> - Direct programmers to native language resources. Users who post non-English questions should be gently directed to programming forums
>   in their own language. Community should form around the gravity of
>   native human languages. (see: Chinatown, Little Italy, etc.) Feel free
>   to post links to appropriate human language-specific resources.
> - It is not our goal to teach English. It is our goal to teach programming. If the post has salvageable English and makes some
>   modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved just like any other
>   post. If it does not, it should be closed.
> - The asker has to put effort into the question. Barging into an obviously English dominated forum and insisting on posting a question
>   in another language is no different than the “do my work for me” sort
>   of programming questions — the worst possible sin on Stack Overflow in
>   my humble opinion. You want us to give you answers? Then prove that
>   you’ve put some effort into the question, and you can begin by
>   politely asking it in the language this community is formed around.

Comment: Well I am not referring to questions posted in another language. I am talking of cases where you can tell the Person doesn't speak English natively and his post could use some correction. And precisely, I think this would be useful for directing users to their native language SO.

Comment: *his post could use some correction* Then you could edit and correct those parts which you think needs correction.

Comment: Well, it is not always so simple, is it? But I understand your point. In any case I think it would still be useful for the purpose of redirecting OPs to their Native language site.

Comment: In that case, I would use the comments section to help OP. If OP posted a question on Stack Overflow, then he would post it in English. Else, it would be anyway closed as off-topic if OP posts in a different language. If the post looks really difficult to be understood due to language issues, it won't be that difficult to ask OP in the comments about his native language.

Comment: But in theory we shouldn't post or chat in other languages, right? I am going to accept your as the answer because you cited the policies and didn't just express your opinion about it being useful or not. I think however that in the future it would be useful if the site could remind users about the SO in their native language, I don't know if something has been done in that regard already.

Comment: *But in theory we shouldn't post or chat in other languages, right?* Yes. Because if a question is posted in a language other than English, then it would be closed.

Answer (score 5):

No, this wouldn't be useful at all.

This is an English-only site, and while I deeply respect that English is not everyone's native tongue, we are required to communicate (questions, answers, comments) exclusively in English.

Adding information like this would only serve to add clutter to the site, as it would literally do nothing for anyone; if they posted a question in their native tongue, it would *very likely* get closed for being off-topic.

Comment: Well, I don't suggest questions, answers or comments should be in another language, precisely to improve the level of the questions without polluting the main site is that I suggest being able to talk with them separetely and fix their post.

Comment: It's still required that one communicate in English.  What happens if a moderator has to intervene in one of these side channels?  You can't guarantee that they understand the language or are polyglots.

Comment: I understand your point, and I guess you can't officially promote helping people in other languages, however it probably happens anyway. I still feel though, that it wouldn't be totally useless, even if you don't open a separate chat in another language, just by knowing what language a person speaks sometimes you can understand better their thought pattern and also it could be useful to point them to the appropriate SO in their language when they get created.

Answer (score 5):

My comment became too long, so I have to write an answer.
You're talking about people who doesn't know English at all. They are able to put text into translator (in the worst case), apologize and in few minutes someone will correct grammar mistakes. *This point is just an example of view*. If it is starting to be a big amount of people without English knowledge there might be created a separated branch for the language. Here we have [StackOverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) which is Beta now. Because I know that Russian IT community is large, but not many people at all can speak English, so they want to increase coefficient of efficiency.

And @Makoto is right, if everyone just add native language to profile it will not help at all, because:

1. If question is clear enough, have some mistakes - someone will correct it;
2. If it is unclear at all - no one will translate it;
3. If there are something about understanding the question - it is rather asking skills and will be a comment with asking to clarify details.

At final, English unify people, not separate. Especially we have [a community for English learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, I am not referring to people that doesn't know English. I am talking of cases that some parts of the text makes no much sense and it could be clarified the easily. Sorry if my post seemed to indicate I wanted to allow people posting questions in whatever language. Yes I don't think that would be correct.

Comment: anyways, it is likely or asked in comments "*what do you mean by **this***" or corrected by someone who understood the point. If in the question some specific details from his/her language written in English, I'd not get it for example, unless person asks me directly in my native language.

Comment: I don't quite follow your last comment. Do you mean you wouldn't understand some things unless they are said in your own language? In any case my proposal was meant only to expedite things not to give freedom for people to post things in whatever language. Also to avoids issues, I know my English is not perfect, but not everyone would accept it so easily, if you start asking people in comments about their native language because they are not clear they could get offended and wind up generating more work for the mods.

Comment: I mean if Russian guy, asked a question in English and it is not clear, I'd not get as any other people with another native language. And info that his native language is Russian will not help me to correct it, because likely it doesn't make sense in English, so I have no idea what is he talking about unless he asks same thing in Russian, but this is restricted. And no, for sure you wouldn't ask about native language in comments, I meant ask some technical details about the question.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. But yes I was referring to cases like that. If you knew Russian you could help him, but since you don't know what he speaks you can't know if you can help him.